# How to make a hover effects like Wikipedia and Facebook

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg

I am trying to make a hovercard effect using SVG and JavaScript such as Wikipedia and Facebook. 
but how to fix the top triangle position when hovering on elements.
I need to fix the triangle position and the hovering action like Wikipedia or facebook.
(NOTE: I have some problem in my css and js link. I am a new programmer, I want to learn more), Sorry for that.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Wikipedia Hover Effects</title>


    <style>
       .content {
 

 font-family: Segoe UI;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  padding: 30px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  line-height: 27px;
}

.v-content-modal {
  position: absolute;
  background: #fff;
  box-shadow: 0 3px 20px 0 #ddd;
  width: 350px;
  border-top: 3px solid #ddd;
  display: none;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.v-content-modal .modal-title {
  background: #f5f5f5;
  padding: 0 1.25rem;
  font-size: .95rem;
  letter-spacing: .03rem;
  line-height: 38px;
  height: 35px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;


}

.v-content-modal .modal-content {
  padding: 1.75rem 1.25rem;
}

.v-content-modal::before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: -23px;
  left: 30px;
  border: 10px solid transparent;
  border-color: transparent transparent #ddd transparent;
}
    </style>
</head>

<body>



    <div class="content">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet <a href="#" data-title="One" data-content="I am the first one/" id="info">One</a>
        adipisicing elit. Quisquam, modi neque! Cupiditate itaque vitae aliquid
        <a href="#" data-title="Two" data-content="I am the Second one/" id="info">Two</a>,
        pariatur qui sequi minima voluptates voluptatibus quae
        nemo! Suscipit <a href="#" data-title="Three" data-content="I am the Third one/" id="info">Three</a> quibusdam
        dignissimos vitae, cum cumque voluptates et hic doloribus dicta, <a href="#" data-title="Four"
            data-content="I am the Forth one/" id="info">Four</a> quos,
        nostrum in.
    </div>

    <div class="v-content-modal">
        <div class="modal-title">
            Title
        </div>
        <div class="modal-content">
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Illo, quam.
        </div>
    </div>

    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
$(function () {
    let modal = $(".v-content-modal");
    let title = $(".v-content-modal > .modal-title");
    let content = $(".v-content-modal > .modal-content");
    let btns = document.querySelectorAll("#info");

    btns.forEach(btn => {
        btn.addEventListener("mousemove", (e) => {
            modal.css({
                top: 'unset',
                right: 'unset',
                left: 'unset',
                bottom: 'unset'
            });

            title.html(e.target.getAttribute('data-title'));
            content.html(e.target.getAttribute('data-content'));

            let pageX, pageY, winWidth, winHeight, elmWidth, elmHeight, width_limit, height_limit = '';
            pageX = e.pageX;
            pageY = e.pageY;
            winWidth = $(window).width();
            winHeight = $(window).height();
            elmWidth = $(".v-content-modal").width();
            elmHeight = $(".v-content-modal").height();
            width_limit = winWidth - elmWidth;
            height_limit = winHeight - elmHeight;

            (pageX > width_limit) ? crossWidth(): normalWidth();
            (pageY > height_limit) ? crossHeight(): normalHeight();

            function crossWidth() {
                modal.css({
                    right: '5px'
                });
            }

            function normalWidth() {
                modal.css({
                    left: pageX
                });
            }

            function crossHeight() {
                modal.css({
                    bottom: '111px'
                });
            }

            function normalHeight() {
                modal.css({
                    top: e.pageY + 30 + 'px'
                });
            }

            // show when all customization is completed...
            modal.show();
        });

        btn.addEventListener("mouseleave", () => {
            modal.hide();
        });
    });

});
   </script>
</body>

</html>
```

**Again,**

```
<div class="content"> 
    Lorem text <a href="/wiki/mark"> Mark Info will show here when you hover </a> Dummy text <a href="/wiki/you"> You will show here when you hover on it</a>
</div>


//Define one time only
<div class="modal" style="display: none">
  <div class="modal-title"> </div>
  <div class="modal-content"> </div>
</div>
```

when you hover on any <a> it will be show all the info by using the link addr "/wiki/mark" or "/wiki/you"

**#we don't need to assign all info every time!**

Comment: Can you give us a link to that "Wikipedia or Facebook hover effect" ? So we can understand what you mean by that.

Comment: Please Run my whole code now!

Comment: The name of that feature is ["Page previews"](https://blog.wikimedia.org/2018/04/18/how-we-designed-page-previews-for-wikipedia/). Twitter use the same feature too.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Bootstrap framework for such an effect. It is very easy!
You connect js and css [Bootstrap](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.2/getting-started/introduction/) files, connect the Poper.js (on the same page) and you can just copy the Bootstrap elements to your project and use it as you want.
You can see the element itself at [this link](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/components/tooltips/). It is called a tooltips.

Comment: I knew it. But It's not dynamic!

Comment: Hm... What do you mean?

Comment: <div class="content"> 
    Lorem text <a href="/wiki/mark"> Mark Info will show here when you hover </a> Dummy text <a href="/wiki/you"> You will show here when you hover on it </a>
 </div>


//Define one time only
<div class="modal" style="display: none">
  <div class="modal-title"> </div>
  <div class="modal-content"> </div>
</div>


when you hover on any <a> it will be show all the info by using the link addr "/wiki/mark" or "/wiki/you" 



#we don't need to assign all info every time!